# I can't adjust my title's position on the header

Tags: html, css

For my website, I'm having a problem where if I adjust the screen size on the inspect element by height, the title in the header will deviate from the position I originally want it fixed in.

[image]

So I tried to fix it by replacing `bottom: 4vh;` with `bottom: 4%;` but instead, it moves the title under the header which was the original position

[image: title]

I tried using `margin-bottom` and `padding-bottom` to fix it but it still won't budge. I don't know what to do.

Here is my code in case you were wondering.

```css
.title {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 16px;
  bottom: 0vh;
  left: 8vh;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 50vh;
  height: 0vh;
}

.img-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 1vh;
}

.nav-links li {
  font-size: 20px;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <logo className = "logo">
          <div className = "img-1">
              <img src = {logo} alt = "Logo" width="43" height="39"></img>
          </div>
          <a className = "title">
              DESSA
          </a>
        </logo>
        <nav>  
            <div  onClick = {this.navSlide} class="hamburger">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>            
            <ul  onClick = {this.navSlide} className="nav-links">                
               <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
               <div className = "img-2">
                 <img src = {search} alt = "Search" width="22" height="22"></img>
               </div>
               <div className = "img-3">
                 <img src = {shop} alt = "Shop" width="36" height="32"></img>
               </div>                               
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against using the "vh" unit at all, based on the website gif you posted. The vh unit is used only in very particular situations, and with caution.

In your website, at least for the header, I would suggest you to use flexbox, to align all the different items and give a nice spacing between them. Regarding the logo, I don't know exactly how you want it, but you can often tweak you object position by setting negative margins, or you can use positioned layout to place some of your decorative elements (like the chain icon in the logo) into a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

try using this it will fixe the postion of the title  .

```css
.before-title {
  positon:relative;
  width:10vw;
  left:1em;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 16px;
  bottom: 0vh;
  left: 8vh;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 50vh;
  height: 0vh;
}

.img-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 2vh;
  left: 1vh;
}

.nav-links li {
  font-size: 20px;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <logo className = "logo">
          <div className = "img-1">
              <img src = {logo} alt = "Logo" width="43" height="39"></img>
          </div>
         <div class='before-title'>
          <a className = "title">
              DESSA
          </a>
        <div>
        </logo>
        <nav>  
            <div  onClick = {this.navSlide} class="hamburger">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>            
            <ul  onClick = {this.navSlide} className="nav-links">                
               <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
               <div className = "img-2">
                 <img src = {search} alt = "Search" width="22" height="22"></img>
               </div>
               <div className = "img-3">
                 <img src = {shop} alt = "Shop" width="36" height="32"></img>
               </div>                               
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
```